# Aggregate query for a single collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

My database contains a user `collection` in the form:

```
{
    "userId": "12345",
    "vertical": "BFS",
    "Role": "Manager"
},
{
    "userId": "12345",
    "vertical": "Insurance",
    "Role": "Manager"
},
{
    "userId": "12367",
    "vertical": "BFS",
    "Role": "Associate"
}
```

I know `vertical` and `manager` and from this I have to find the `userId`. Then I have to find the `verticals` of the particular user.

Like in SQL:

```
select vertical 
from user 
where role="Manager" 
    and userid in (
        select userid from user 
        where vertical="BFS" and role="Manager"
    )
```

Kindly help on this. I am new to this technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:** We would like to get the data where a manager in **BFS** vertical is playing the Manager role in other verticals as well.

I would handle this problem with **aggregate framework** available in MongoDB.

Here is the explanation foe each pipeline in the below query.

1) $Match - Get all data where role is Manager because we are interested in manager role only

2) $project - Just an interim pipeline to project the fields to next pipeline

3) $group - Similar to SQL to group the data by userId and add their verticals to an array

4) $Match - To filter the userids where they are part of BFS

```
db.vertical.aggregate([
   {$match : { "Role": "Manager"}},
   {$project : { "userId" : 1, "vertical" : 1, "Role" : 1}},
   {$group : { _id : "$userId", "verticalsArray" : {$push : "$vertical"} } },
   {$match : { "verticalsArray": "BFS"}},
]);
```

**Output:-**

```
{
    "_id" : "12345",
    "verticalsArray" : [ 
        "BFS", 
        "Insurance"
    ]
}
```

Comment: wouldn't this break for something like this -{
    "userId": "12345",
    "vertical": "BFS",
    "Role": "Manager"
},
{
    "userId": "12345",
    "vertical": "Insurance",
    "Role": "Associate"
} since he needs to find all verticals for user id 12345.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. I have tried with the sample data that is given in the question and my answer has the output assuming I understood your problem correctly. I have summarized my understanding as well in my answer.

Comment: It will break for the data I gave. A person can have different designations for different verticals. Your $match phase will remove the document for userid 12345 where he is not the manager and you wont get his vertical for that doc.

Comment: The last match (step 4) in my query is equals to array contains BFS. If the array has BFS and Insurance, it would get the user id in the output. Just to confirm, this is the tested code and it works fine for the data you have provided.

Comment: Well I understand what you are saying. His SQL says the user should be a Manager but his question says he wants to find all the verticals of that particular user. Guess he will have to decide.

Comment: Well, my solution is based on the given SQL query. Sometimes, the statements doesn't explain the requirements clearly or could be interpreted in different ways.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH,IT WORKS PERFECT